# What is elevation doing in Android L?

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, android-elevation

Today I developed my first Android L Apps, and read through the d.android.com/preview tips. They said that android:elevation would show me shadows. But look at this:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvTest5"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_below="@id/btnTest1"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/tvTest4"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:elevation="50dp"/>
```

I don't see any shadow in my Emulator.
Am I doing something wrong or is the Emulator buggy?
I'm using Android Studio

Comment: Which Android version your emulator running on?

Comment: im compiling with android L api 20 so i guess the newest. I updated everything

Comment: Try a lower value, like 5dp. Maybe you added a too big elevation, so the shadow is totally blurred out. Maybe also because you need to do more [stuff](https://developer.android.com/preview/material/views-shadows.html).

Comment: It is not the same - you should do both: compile with latest target (which you're already doing) and run app on emulator with Android L Preview installed. I assume that you're not doing that, since elevation of `50dp` should be pretty noticeable by itself.

Comment: the android avd hast target Android L api level L

Comment: Please, provide a sreenshot

Comment: [link](http://www.pic-upload.de/view-23767145/AVDPreviewL.png.html)

Comment: I meant screenshot from emulator :) I do believe you :)

Comment: haha :D [link](http://www.pic-upload.de/view-23767270/AVDPreviewLEmulator.png.html)

Comment: I don't see any `TextView` with `#000000` background

Comment: the right one :D when i click the button all of them change the color ;)

Comment: How about you'll create layout with a single `TextView` that you presented to us without any logic?

Comment: What is the value of View.isHardwareAccelerated() on your TextView? Are you using host GPU / GPU emulation on your AVD?

Comment: What worked for me is having a shape as the background. They probably still have issues with figuring out what the shadow shape should be with just colors. My guess.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android AppCompat 21 Elevation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26728570/android-appcompat-21-elevation)

Comment: i normally set "3sp" as elevation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I kinda solved it. The problem was the emulator. We now have ordered a Nexus 5 and flashed Android L. Now it works fine

Answer (score 0):

You should see the elevation when you create two views with different z-index.

Answer (score 0):

You should watch the video talking about it:

[Google I/O 2014 - Material science: Developing Android applications with material](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lSH9aKXjgt8)

They said there that elevation has weird issues if the Z value isn't different between views.

It starts at about 15:00 .