# Android AppCompat 21 Elevation

Tags: android, android-view, material-design

Is there any way to add elevation to a `View` in pre-lollipop devices without wrapping them in a `CardView`?

Comment: Refer here: http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2014/10/appcompat-v21-material-design-for-pre.html They have said it for the Action bar as getSupportActionBar().setElevation(0). So try the same for your card view.

Comment: I'm not looking to add elevation to a `CardView`. I would like to add it to any `View` if possible.

Answer (score 80, accepted):

`ViewCompat.setElevation(View, int)` currently creates no shims.

The only way to simulate elevation right now is to apply a shadow pre-v21. Define your style/layout/drawable in `values` and override it in `values-v21`. For buttons I use style overrides. For layouts, I usually go for reference override (use `@null` to get rid of a drawable).

Hopefully in the future an update to the support library will add shims.

[This reddit thread](http://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/2kd843/so_how_are_you_guys_doing_with_your_current/) keeps track of said update.

#### Edit

The new [support design library](http://android-developers.blogspot.co.uk/2015/05/android-design-support-library.html) actually does create shims for the floating action button.

Comment: This is still not working right? What exactly are 'shims' :) ?

Comment: @DanielWilson a shim is a workaround (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shim_(computing)). Since the shadows are native in 5.0, you need a shim for < 5.0

Comment: Very interesting thankyou :) Well hopefully the engineers won't abandon this for older devices. I'd rather not do it myself :D

Comment: @DanielWilson well to be honest: Material Design is part of the 5.0+ generation. It doesn't really make "sense" having it pre lollipop. I think that and not having the renderthread are reasons why it won't be supported.

Comment: @Derk-Jan unfortunately Android 5 is < 2% market share even months after you wrote that

Comment: @GregEnnis Well it's 3.3%; but yes, its all waiting and waiting.

Comment: Hey what exactly do you mean by ref override? can you post an example?

Comment: Sorry ,but it doesn't work on code. My device is android4.1, and I added the newest android-support-v4.jar

Comment: @AaronLee "[...] creates no shims". See the 'no'

Answer (score 65):

This is an example how to add a shadow below the `Toolbar` on pre-lollipop devices:

[image]

The layout should be this:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/toolbar_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_shadow"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/toolbar_shadow"
        android:layout_below="@id/toolbar"
        android:background="@drawable/toolbar_dropshadow" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

And the shadow is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" >

    <gradient
        android:angle="90"
        android:endColor="#88444444"
        android:startColor="@android:color/transparent" />

</shape>
```

Comment: can you give information about -   android:layout_height="@dimen/toolbar_shadow"

Comment: it is the size of the shadow, higher the value, more "elevated" the toolbar is

Comment: According to value picked from google design website the endColor should be #45000000. However, it depends on where the value acquired anyway.

Comment: Such a simple solution.  Thank you!

Answer (score 48):

I achieve same effect using,

```
  android:background="@android:drawable/dialog_holo_light_frame"
```

**My tested output:**

[image]

reference - https://stackoverflow.com/a/25683148/3879847

**Update :** If you want change color of this drawable try @Irfan answer

https://stackoverflow.com/a/40815944/3879847

Comment: I used this trick for a RecyclerView adapter and worked great. Thanks for sharing!

Comment: How to do I do this for AlertDialog ? I have a style that is applied to dialog so I added the mentioned attribute there but it looks weird. It looks as if I have added multiple sheets/layers as background. Any clue ?

Comment: Using of system resources like @android:drawable/dialog_holo_light_frame is dangerous, isn't it? Some producers of mobile devices can override system resources, so this resources may be displayed differently on different devices, isn't it?

Comment: I Using this resource more than 2 years.. Still, I am not getting any issues.. It's working in Samsung, Asus, Nexus, moto.. And Lenovo also..

Answer (score -5):

You can now use the schema `xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"` and `app:elevation`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
...

<LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
            app:elevation="5dp">
```

Comment: for view must use appcompact like 'android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView'