# Elevation on pre-L devices?

Tags: android, material-design

I've noticed that `elevation` is part of the v7 support library.

When applying it to buttons through styles.xml, I don't see any elevation being applied.

Is it supposed to work on pre-L devices? If not, why is it present in the support library ?

Comment: I'd love to have a definite answer too but what I've found out is that elevation is only available for Cardview.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android AppCompat 21 Elevation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26728570/android-appcompat-21-elevation)

Answer (score 3):

The elevation works only in Android 5.0. On earlier versions, shadows are normally provided as PNG assets.

Comment: Then what's the point of having it available on the support library? Will it be available in the future ?