# Elevation effect for ImageButton on Pre-Lollipop devices

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, material-design

I am trying the apply elevation effect for ImageButton. It works well on my Nexus tablet running Android 5.0 but elevation does not work on Pre-Lollipop devices.

Tried ViewCompat.setElevation(view, evaluationValue) but nothing changed.

I saw some applications like Swarm or Gmail apps use elevation effect for their FAB (Floating Action Button) on Pre-Lollipop devices.

Do you have an idea how they use elevation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot use elevation pre 5.0, you need to provide an image with a "shadow" to make it appear like its elevated

Comment: There is more information about this here http://stackoverflow.com/a/26747592/1568429 Also in this reddit thread http://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/2kd843/so_how_are_you_guys_doing_with_your_current/

Answer (score 0):

It's true than you cannot do it now but for different reason.

There is a setElevation method inter support library for pre Lollipop. But I think it's buggy and still is not usable with all types of views.

Check it out here

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewCompat.html#setElevation(android.view.View,%20float)

Edit: sorry, I noticed now you already tried it. I hope Google has plans to fix this soon

Comment: ViewCompat methods don't bring new functionality to older APIs. They simply provide methods that can safely be called and no-op on older APIs.

Comment: It's not buggy it is empty, not implemented.

Answer (score 0):

as mentioned in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30778189/how-to-implement-the-material-design-elevation-for-pre-lollipop) set background to

android:background="@android:drawable/dialog_holo_light_frame"

it looks like raised button on pre lollipop.