# How to have an Elevated Button with Color background for Prelollipop?

Tags: android, android-button, android-elevation

As posted in https://stackoverflow.com/a/30931750, for Prelollipop, we could have shadow (elevation) for our button by setting the following.

```
android:background="@android:drawable/dialog_holo_light_frame"
```

However, if I need to add another color to my button background, how could I achieve that?

(Additional question, is there a way to control the elevation (depth of shadow) using this appraoch?)

Comment: Define button properties in style.xml file and you can control the elevation by using android:elevation tag

Comment: android:elevation tag can't be used for Prelollipop :(