# Android Widget Shadow which supports from API 16

Tags: android, widget, shadow, android-elevation

I want to have shadow in Android widget like button, edittext, searchview or anything. I have no idea about android elevation. I think it only supports from API 23. If there is any proper solution then please provide.

here is my demo widget. I need the shadow in border of my searchview.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.SearchView
    android:id="@+id/searchView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:backgroud="@android:color/white" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place your views inside CardView. Using CardView you can add elevation, rounded corners etc. It supports back till API 7.

to use CardView, add it via your app level gradle..

```
dependencies {

...

    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.3.1'
}
```

Comment: can you please provide the cardview code with elevation?

Answer (score 1):

You can get the shadow effect by adding this to the widget:

```
android:background="@android:drawable/dialog_holo_light_frame"
```

Got the answer from here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30931750/8466860.

Comment: if i want to change the background color of my widget with any colors besides the shadow then how to do it.