# Elevation and shade in Imagebutton Android

Tags: android, android-layout

Does anyone know how I can add shadow and elevation to imagebuttons and spinner?

The way it's placed it only works in Android Studio. When I run on a device with android API 17 it does not work.

In Android Studio it appears as if it is high, but when I run on a device it does not work and looks like the image

[Layout currently](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RoBA6.png)

This is my xml layout:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:mapbox="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.MapView
        android:id="@+id/mapView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
        mapbox:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        mapbox:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        mapbox:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        mapbox:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        mapbox:mapbox_cameraTargetLat="-36.84"
        mapbox:mapbox_cameraTargetLng="174.76"
        mapbox:mapbox_cameraZoom="16">


    </com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.MapView>

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/btnNotifications"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="148dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:background="@drawable/circle_button"
        android:elevation="3dp"
        android:padding="10dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/btnProfileUser"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.019"
        mapbox:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_notification"
        tools:ignore="VectorDrawableCompat" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/btnProfileUser"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:background="@drawable/circle_button"
        android:elevation="3dp"
        android:padding="10dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/btnNotifications"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.789"
        mapbox:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_user"
        tools:ignore="VectorDrawableCompat" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/cardSpinner"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:elevation="3dp"
        android:innerRadius="0dp"
        android:shape="ring"
        android:thicknessRatio="1.9"
        app:cardCornerRadius="20dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/mapView"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.015">

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinTypeVehicle"
            android:layout_width="190dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp" />



    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: does it work on latest API level phones?

Answer (score 0):

You are using `android:elevation`, which is not available for api < 21

This solution may work: [How to implement the Material-design Elevation for Pre-lollipop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30778189/how-to-implement-the-material-design-elevation-for-pre-lollipop)