# Elevation/shadows for layouts in pre-lollipop

Tags: android, android-styles, android-elevation

Am trying to add elevation to my layouts in styles but the `android:elevation` is only available for lollipop not pre lollipop. This is my layout in v21. [image: which am trying to achieve for pre-lollipop]

My styles for v14

```
    <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
        <!-- API 14 theme customizations can go here. -->
<android:elevation="4dp"> // Doesn't work here 
</style>
```

Is it possible to achieve this effect? Any pointers will be great. Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Elevation effect for ImageButton on Pre-Lollipop devices](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27432343/elevation-effect-for-imagebutton-on-pre-lollipop-devices)

Comment: This is not a duplicate. The disconnect text is actually a  textview not a button

Answer (score 0):

No you cannot add elevation in pre-Lollipop devices.

Still you can use a shadow like image and put it there to get such an effect. But it is not a good idea.

Comment: So your saying I should add shadow images around my layouts? That seems illogical.

Comment: Ha Ha. That's why developers say don't use shadow property in pre-lollipop devices. nobody will recommend you that. Leave it as it is.

Answer (score 0):

So i found a solution to my problem and felt i should post it. Those that wish to achieve the elevation effect should just add this to their layout  `android:background="@android:drawable/dialog_holo_light_frame` . This gives an elevated effect on any layout.