# "android:elevation=" doesn't work on devices pre-Lollipop with compile API21

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, android-elevation

I'm trying to use `"android: elevation ="` in my application but once I run it does not appear in the device with android 4.1.2

**gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.alvaro.proyectocaronte"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
}
```

**layout.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="1100dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:background="@drawable/rounded_corner"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_marginRight="93dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="93dp"
                android:elevation="3dp"/>
```

maybe I'm not compiling correctly Lollipop for pre-lollipop devices, Any suggestions?

If you need to see other parts of the code, I'll edit the question

Thanks

Comment: late comment.. But surely helps to anyone.. try this - http://stackoverflow.com/a/30962710/3879847

Comment: Thanks @RanjithKumar, surely helps!! nice job.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Elevation requires the device to run Lollipop. See this answer on how to simulate elevation https://stackoverflow.com/a/26747592/680249

Answer (score 21):

***UPDATED*** ::

1. **Best Practice** to do that is

   ```
   <android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
       <YourLayout>
   </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
   ```

   and add library for cardview

   ```
   dependencies {
      ...
      compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:21.0.+'
    }
   ```
2. On **Pre-Lollipop** you can use this **drawable**

   android:background="@android:drawable/dialog_holo_light_frame"

   it will give you the **look of elevation**
3. you can create your own like this

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

   <item>
   <shape android:shape="rectangle">
       <solid android:color="#BDBDBD"/>
       <corners android:radius="5dp"/>
   </shape>
   </item>

   <item
   android:left="0dp"
   android:right="0dp"
   android:top="0dp"
   android:bottom="2dp">
   <shape android:shape="rectangle">
       <solid android:color="#ffffff"/>
       <corners android:radius="5dp"/>
   </shape>
   </item>
   </layer-list>
   ```

[reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25683148/3879847)

Answer (score 12):

You can also use a CardView from the support library 
to implement surfaces.
To do so add a dependency to your build.gradle:

```
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.1.1'
```

And then simply use it in your layouts:

```
  <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="150dp"
      android:layout_margin="16dp"
      android:background="#fff"
      >
  </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Here you have a quite more options to customise it comparing to 
using `@android:drawable/dialog_holo_light_frame` as a background

EDIT:
Also notice, that **this approach allows** you to simply implement
Material Design **on Pre-Lolipop devices**.
You can change the elevation,
round the corners etc.
To do so you have to:

```
 app:cardElevation="8dp"
 app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
 app:contentPadding="5dp">
```

And not forget to add `xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"`
to the root layout.

Also you can easily change the elevation in your code:

```
CardView card = (CardView) findViewById(R.id.yourPreetyCoolCardView);
card.setCardElevation(getResources()
    .getDimension(R.dimen.card_picked_up_elevation));
```

Use `8dp` for picked up and `2dp` for resting (usual) state and you will be awesome.

Answer (score 1):

As described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30931750/8460132), you can mimic the elevation on pre-lollipop with:

```
 android:background="@android:drawable/dialog_holo_light_frame"
```