# setElevation( ) for LinearLayout before 5.0 devices

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, android-elevation

Hi I'm trying to apply a shadow to a linearlayout with the following code

`if (<some condition>)
    layout.setElevation(4);`

but this call requires API level 21 to work. How can I apply a shadow to layouts for devices with version < 5.0? Is it possible?

I know this is part of Material Design which is why I just want to know if there is a way to achieve something similar in previous versions, thanks :)

Comment: You can follow this thread of SO. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31115531/add-elevation-shadow-on-toolbar-for-pre-lollipop-devices

Comment: this might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26728570/android-appcompat-21-elevation

Comment: http://blog.grafixartist.com/add-a-toolbar-elevation-on-pre-lollipop/ - this showed me how to use xml to achieve the same. thanks! :)

Answer (score 13):

Use ViewCompat.setElevation(view, elevation);

Comment: What API level does this work back since? (are all the methods in ViewCompat from api level 4+ unless specified in the documentation?)

Comment: The code of the call in **androidx.core.view.ViewCompat (1.0.1)** is literally the following:
`public static void setElevation(@NonNull View view, float elevation) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
            view.setElevation(elevation);
        }
    }`
So, I doubt it's going to have the desired effect.