# AppBarLayout elevation change is delayed on appCompat v24.0.0

Tags: android, android-elevation, android-appcompat

In **Appcompat v24.0.0** causes rendering of *shadow/elevation* to `AppbarLayout` after Activity is visible. And a lag can easily be seen in shadow drawing to `AppbarLayout`.

And this lag was not there in previous Appcompat library version.

Tested using both *Appcompat v24.0.0* and *Appcompat v23.4.0*, shadow drawing clearly seen in the new version.

Comment: And what is your question for the StackOverflow community? Maybe you should file a bug report for the appcompat team.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**This is a bug in `Appcompat v24.0.0`**.

> References: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=213895

In order to minimize the delay in `elevation` drawing, set the duration to **1ms** in your own `StateListAnimator` and apply it to `AppbarLayout`.

**appbar_always_elevated.xml** in ***animator-v21*** folder under ***res*** directory.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item>
        <objectAnimator android:propertyName="elevation"
                        android:valueTo="8dp"
                        android:valueType="floatType"
                        android:duration="1"/>
    </item>

</selector>
```

In AppbarLayout :

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:stateListAnimator="@animator/appbar_always_elevated"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

Comment: @JoaoSousa answer updated with your suggestion. I too got the same error while placing state list animator, so I placed in "animator-v21" and that worked like a charm removing that error.

Comment: @Vipul Asri So if the correct folder to place the state list animator is "anim-v21" why is it showing an error? where should I put it?

Comment: @ItielMaimon If its showing error it will still work fine during runtime. But if you want to remove this error just refactor your `anim-v21` to `animator-v21`. As selector tag is not recognizable in `anim-v21` as of now.

Comment: I removed my previous comment because it was plain wrong. After reading through the officials docs I stand corrected. The correct folder name should be `animator-v21`.

Answer (score 15):

Chris Banes said [here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=213895#c18):

> The StateListAnimator owns all elevation handling now. If you want to do it yourself, set a null StateListAnimator and call setElevation() as you please.

So if your `AppBarLayout` is *not collapsible* you can use this:

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:stateListAnimator="@null"
    android:elevation="@dimen/design_appbar_elevation">
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. It makes design 24.0.0 behave like its older version.

Comment: @MarcelWesołowski Only if you don't use CollapsibleToolbarLayout.

Comment: @EugenPechanec I'm using `CollapsibleToolbarLayout` and it works fine. This should be accepted answer.

Comment: @Sandak The AppBarLayout should *not* have a shadow when it's expanded. Enforcing a shadow (what this post suggests) may be fine for you but it overrides intended and expected behavior.

Answer (score 10):

I guess it is not a bug, a feature.

AppBarLayout's elevation animation duration is controlled by [`R.integer.app_bar_elevation_anim_duration`](https://github.com/dandar3/android-support-design/blob/0c0e9323e1b0f76dadc643e0f6f87da968e5ba80/res/values/values.xml#L225) which by default is `150`.

To remove the animation, just do the following and that's it:

`<integer name="app_bar_elevation_anim_duration" tools:override="true">0</integer>`

Comment: Agree, if it is a bug, they should fixed this when newer version of appcompat lib release, I am using 25.1.1 and still have the slow issue. lol

Comment: This definitely should be accepted as a right answer

Answer (score 1):

@Vipul Asri given us a good answer, but the **appbar_always_elevated.xml** should be into ***animator-v11*** instead of ***animator-v21*** folder. The layout that has the **AppbarLayout** is that should be into a v21 folder.

Summarising, the structure is like this:

```
-res
   -animator-v11
      -appbar_always_elevated.xml
   -layout
      -a_layout_wich_has_the_appbarlayout.xml
   -layout-v21
      -a_layout_wich_has_the_appbarlayout.xml
```

Note that there are two **a_layout_wich_has_the_appbarlayout.xml** files (**AppbarLayout** in **v21** folder with android:stateListAnimator property and in a non **v21** folder without this property).

Take a look:

In a non **v21** layout folder:

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
```

And, in **v21** layout folder:

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:stateListAnimator="@animator/appbar_always_elevated">
```

**EDIT**

Curiously, if you are using the **AppbarLayout** with a **TabLayout**, the shadow is drawn instantly, but notice that if you are using with the android:stateListAnimator property this case, the shadow view is a bit different.