# Android onClick not working on some android versions

Tags: android, onclick, android-xml

I have set a couple of `TextView`s to call a method using the XML `OnClick` parameter. It works fine on a Lollipop device but it doesn't work on KitKat or older Android versions.

Why does it happen? Is there a way I can solve it without setting listeners for each view id?

Comment: can you add you java and xml code? I have an sugestion but i need to see the code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `android:clickable="true"` in your textview.

In alternative, you  can put your click logic in source code:

```
textView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
```

Comment: it worked correctly this is the correct answer for my problem, so the explanation is that the view needs to be android:clickable="true" in order to be compatible with android versions older than lollipop.

Comment: It seems like onClick does set the clickable attribute in Android 5.0 Lollipop (API 21).

Comment: LOL I'm very happy to have found this answer.. but... what the hell is the reasoning behind this??  should it be called clickableOnAPI19orLess. ??

Answer (score 0):

Without any code I have to assume that, since you're talking about challenges with pre-lollipop devices, you're having trouble with elevation values.

Check out this link: 
   [Add elevation/shadow on toolbar for pre-lollipop devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31115531/add-elevation-shadow-on-toolbar-for-pre-lollipop-devices)