# Show shadows under toolbars if they are supported

Tags: android

I am targeting api 17, and I would like to have shadows on devices that support material design. Is there something like "If shadows supported, use shadows"?

Comment: You mean your `targetSdkVersion` is 17? or `minSdkVersion` is 17?

Comment: Oh sorry, I meant minSdkVersion.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [No shadow by default on Toolbar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26575197/no-shadow-by-default-on-toolbar)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31115531/add-elevation-shadow-on-toolbar-for-pre-lollipop-devices/32393698

Comment: Adding `android:elevation="<your-dimen-in-dp>"` this attribute to your toolbar gives you shadow. Still if you thing no stackoverflow question are helping you, then please post your code for further assistance.

Answer (score 0):

Adding android:elevation did solve it.

I thought that this attribute will crash on pre-lollipop devices, as it is not shown in layout editor when minSDK is set to less than 21.