# ImageView should always be above all

Tags: java, android, xml, layout, imageview

I created a fun application.
I created a ImageView which is always above all like an Floating Action Button.
The problem ist: everything works fine at Android 5.0 or higher and it looks like this:
https://gyazo.com/0f02bbe0130defd03cc5ce6282d8e321

And on every device with Android 4 it looks like this:
https://gyazo.com/9275e291f215d92d5e7f2b8740a3d749

This is the code for the ImageView:

```
   <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageButton4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/infoicon"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:maxWidth="25dp"
        android:maxHeight="25dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:elevation="10dp"/>
```

this line should elevate the ImageView:

```
android:elevation="10dp"
```

Why is it working on Android version 5 or higher but on Android version 4 not?

Comment: try to put your imageview with framelayout

Comment: See this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27693843/androidelevation-doesnt-work-on-devices-pre-lollipop-with-compile-api21

Comment: Elevation property started with API 21, older API versions can't execute that layout command.

Comment: @MarceloFerracin is there no way to do it with API 20 or older?

Comment: @debo.stackoverflow this is an explanation on how to ad shadows to an button. But not helpful in my case

Comment: If your root element is a RelativeLayout, the XML elements order matters. So, in theory, if you put your ImageView in last, it should be with the higher Z-axis.

Comment: Oh, I think I forgott to say that I have a Fragment and a MainActivity. So the ImageView is in my MainActivity and the buttons which are in Android version 4 above the ImageView are in the Fragment. So I want that the ImageView of the MainActivity is above the Buttons in the Fragment.

Comment: Ok in this case you have to create a `<FrameLayout>` on your activity, before your ImageView, and you have to call your fragment with: `getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame_layout_id, yourFragment, TAG).commit();`

Comment: This is how I call my Fragment:https://pastebin.com/VMeqXc5u and this is my ImageView in my FrameLayout: https://pastebin.com/PYMp90A0 still not working

Comment: The ImageView is inside your FrameLayout. It should belongs to the same parent of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try calling this:

```
imageView.bringToFront();
```

in `onCreate()` and `onResume()`

**EDIT**

try wrapping your imageview inside `Framelayout`

```
    <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageButton4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:elevation="10dp"
        android:maxHeight="25dp"
        android:maxWidth="25dp"
        android:src="@drawable/infoicon" />
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: It doesn't work if I write imageView.bringToFront(); in my onCreate() it still looks like this https://gyazo.com/9275e291f215d92d5e7f2b8740a3d749

Answer (score 0):

`android:elevation` was added in API level 21, therefore it will work only on Android devices having API level 21 or more.

If you need to provide elevation for devices below API level 21, please refer [How to implement the Material-design Elevation for Pre-lollipop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30778189/how-to-implement-the-material-design-elevation-for-pre-lollipop)

Comment: The link doesn't explain this case