# Android : Card view not run in lower version of "Android L"

Tags: android

I am developing an app for **Card View**.Implement two features of card view "**setRadius()**"  and "**setElevation()**" .It is working fine in Android L.

But when I run the app in API 19 (KitKat) , card view **setElevation()** getting an error

**java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: android.view.View.setElevation"**

Can any one please help me to make this app compatible to all version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

possible duplicated.
[Android AppCompat 21 Elevation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26728570/android-appcompat-21-elevation)

Basically setElevation from ViewCompat won't even work.

Comment: Thanks.,...,  ViewCompat.setElevation(View, int) @WenChao this work fine

Comment: is there any possible way for Elevation shadow effect in android lower version

Comment: Hi Binil, I don't think the pre-Lollipop view's has the elevation attributes. Even the method is there, it will just simply ignored. The only way as mentioned in the link is to use shapes instead. Thanks.

Comment: Hi WenChao , I try by editing in XML just add card_view:cardElevation="10dp" and its working

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the docs for [setElevation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setElevation(float)) and you can see that it was added in API 21 (which is Lollipop).

You can, however, use the [ViewCompat](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewCompat.html) library's version of setElevation, and then it should work on lower API levels.