# Android application error in eclipse

Tags: android

Whenever i run the code as an application in my `Eclipse` it shows an *error*:

```
\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:150: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:windowElevation'.
```

But the example files runs. How to rectify it?

Answer (score 0):

First check your `minApi`:

> Notice that `android:windowElevation` works for `API > 20`

If your `API` is right:

> make sure you have installed `Android 5.0 SDK` via the `SDK-Manager`

For `pre-lollipop` devices check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26728570/android-appcompat-21-elevation)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your appcompat_v7 targeting Android 5.0 or later.

Answer (score 0):

change this line in your **style.xml** file

```
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
```

to :

```
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light">
```