# How to have CardViews seamlessly stack (like Inbox by Gmail) pre-5.0

Tags: android, android-layout, android-support-library, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

I am implementing an interface that stacks `CardViews` in a `RecyclerView`, and my desired result is similar to Inbox by Gmail. As you can see in this screenshot, it works great on 5.0+! *This is exactly what I want*.

[image: 5.0+ stacked CardViews (what I want across all API versions)]

But 4.4 and earlier do not have access to the `android:elevation` attribute, so there's a visual separation between the elements.

[image: 4.4- stacked CardViews (do not want)]

Now, there's an attribute  [`android.support.v7.cardview:cardUseCompatPadding`](http://android.support.v7.cardview:cardUseCompatPadding) that will make API 21+ work like API 20 and below, but I want the opposite (to have 4.4 behave like 5.0). How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a FrameLayout or a RelativeLayout as the parent of your item views to get that consistent look. If your item layout looks like the following:

```
<CardView android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent">

        ...
 </CardView>
```

You can just replace the CardView element with a FrameLayout:

```
 <FrameLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent">
        ...
 </FrameLayout>
```

In RecyclerView.Adapter.onCreateViewHolder, you will return the latter item layout.

Comment: You mean something like this? `RecyclerView` -> `FrameLayout` -> `CardView`? Where each `FrameLayout` that contains a `CardView` is a child of the `RecyclerView`?

Comment: You would just toss out the CardView all together. There's no need to use a CardView here because it seems that you are trying to get the visual feel of a tile: https://www.google.com/design/spec/components/lists.html#lists-usage. I just updated my answer.

Comment: But I want the elevation that comes with a cardview. If you put Inbox in landscape on a phablet or tablet, you can see that each view is a card and has elevation, even pre 4.4.

Comment: You can use a background that will give you a similar effect. I found this post: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30962710/361902 that could help you with it.